# OpenCart: Paypal Session Time-Out

Tags: paypal, opencart

I am using the standard paypal payment method with my opencart website. When I go through the checkout process and get redirected to the PayPal website, I get to login and choose my payment source on the paypal site. However, when it starts processing, it just returns "Your session has timed out, please log in again." and logs me out of Paypal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening in the Sandbox? Were you previously signed into a different PayPal account before the transaction process (within ten minutes)?

Answer (score 0):

I had facing this problem also. If you are using sandbox mode, You should be gave test account for buyer(buyer account must be business account) and also seller account must be individual account(personal). for example `xxx@gmail.com` is buyer account you should put it in admin panel paypal extension,then you should login in E-store website with seller account`(yyy@gmail.com)` and proceed to paypal it will works well.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the cookies that Paypal sets are really annoying, try cleaning all of them, it helped me with other Paypal related errors.